# How to recover Facebook account using email, not phone number

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, facebook-account

I forget my Facebook password and I want to recover it.
But when I recover the password, they send the verify code (6 digits) to the phone number that I no longer use.
[image]

I opened my Facebook account with Gmail and I can access to this Gmail. And I can't see any option to send verify code to email. How can I recover the account using email?

Comment: @pnuts , no . I don't see any option for email recovery like this link said .

Comment: And what happens when you click "No longer have access to these?"

Comment: They said 'Please try logging in from a device you usually use or a location you're usually in when using Facebook. If you log in from a recognised device or location, we may be able to verify that you're the owner of the account and help you gain access.' ,  I've tried it , but no luck .

Comment: Yes , I set up my account with Gmail , phone number is added later . But this number is no longer use .

Answer (score 1):

> You may be able to get back into your Facebook account by answering a security question, using an alternate email address listed on your account or [getting help from friends](https://www.facebook.com/help/215543298568604?helpref=faq_content). Keep in mind that you'll only see these options if you set them up.

[Identify your account](https://www.facebook.com/login/identify)

Click on above link and enter your email address or phone number or username to search for your account.

Once you enter the detail it will redirect you to **Get a six-digit code to recover your account** page, there it will ask your choice that *how do you want to receive your six-digit code in order to recover your account?*

- Send code via email
- Send code via SMS

Select the first choice and click on **Continue** and then follow the screen instructions.
[image]

If you do not have access of your email and mobile number, click [No longer have access to these?](https://www.facebook.com/recover/extended?no_access=1) link, it will redirect you on new page where you have to give additional information so Facebook can reach you, click on Continue and follow the screen instructions.[image]

For more information see the [Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/132243923516844?helpref=faq_content).
[How can I get back into my account?](https://www.facebook.com/help/117450615006715?helpref=related)

Comment: Yes , i see only "Send code via SMS" , no option for "via email" .

Comment: I've edited my question , that's all I can see .

Comment: Are you sure you have an email address associated with your account? I guess you have only mobile number. Try other methods like answering security questions, asking from friends to recover your account if you have set these options.

Comment: Yes , Of course , I have an email address associate with my account , I can even search my facebook account with this Gmail and I can log-in to this Gmail.

Comment: I am not getting redirected to ''How can we reach you?" screen. I don't have email connected to facebook nor I have access to both of mobile number. I just get redirected to"No phone access screen"