# Reset Facebook password

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

My wife forgot her Facebook password and we thought that we will set new password using reset password. So she logged out from her Android Facebook app and now we are not able to reset the password. It sends reset code to email even though the account was registered through phone number only.

What's happening on mobile when we try to reset password:

when phone number is entered as username and clicked on forgotten password, this screen appears [image], now we don't know which email it is sending the 6 digit code. Have checked all my email we have, not receiving code anywhere. (I am not sure but I think there is something missing in the blank part after `Enter the Code We Sent To`)

What's happening on desktop when we try to reset password:

When again username/phone number is entered as username and clicked on forgotten password, this screen appears [image],now if I click on "I cannot access my email account" it goes to this screen [image] where there is nothing to do, if I click on "Try again" it goes to login screen. I am stuck in this cycle. There are many articles like trusted friends and all but I am not able to reach there, this thing just looping in cycle and I don't get any other option. And can't even find anything to contact Facebook for this.

I was thinking that I would receive the code/reset thing on phone which I have access to. But its not working.

Does anyone have idea what's happening here and how to reset my password or how to contact Facebook for this if something is wrong here.

Comment: When we click on forget password, Facebook gives option where do you want to receive your password. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/110262/87130). Was you mobile number verified? Have you ever received security related sms on your mobile from Facebook?

Comment: Its strange that facebook is not asking where to receive the code for this account ( i have confirmed with other accounts it works as you told but not for this account)
i guess the number was verified. (Does it allow for > 1 years fb account without verified number?)

Comment: have confirmed, the number was verified, had earliar did a reset through sms code last year, still have those messages in the phone